# Pre header Variable Question

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hello I'm fairly new with Marketing Cloud but trying my best to be on top of it.

I'm doing a campaign wherein I include the number of days left for someone to redeem their freebies. I set the expiration date to Jan 31 2020.

I had it added on the pre header of my email and was successful doing it. Now I have several expiration date and I don't know how to update the script.

Here's the script for my pre header with fixed expiration date:

```
%%[
var @preheader 
set @expires = "01/31/20" 
set @date = Now() 
set @preheader = DateDiff(@date, @expires, "D") 
]%%

%%=v(@preheader)=%% days left
```

**It will show as:**

[image]

**is there a way to get the @expires based on the info in my data extension?**

I have 7 columns in my DE with the 7th as "Expires" as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are basically looking to fill the `@expires` variable from a DE, instead of hard coded in the script.

So, if this info is inside the sendable DE, you can do:
`SET @expires = AttributeValue('Expires') //Where 'Expires is the column name of your DE`

If its stored elsewhere, you will need to have a 'foreign key' (basically a matching value) to connect your sendable DE to your lookup DE.  For example, let's say that EmailAddress is on both DEs.  You would do the following to find the Expires data:
`SET @expires = Lookup('myLookupDE', 'Expires",'EmailAddress',emailaddr) //Where 'myLookupDE' is the name of your lookup Data Extension`

I would also recommend utilizing `Now(1)` or `GetSendTime` so that the VAWP, etc. (AMPscript is rerun each time it is open) match the values on your email.

Comment: Thanks for this @gortonington it did worked for the attributevalue